# How to break out recursive call

Tags: c#, recursion

How to break out recursive as below:

call `GetDirectory("D:\Engine\", "102")`

expected output: D:\Engine\Type\Tone_Id_102
currently, output is null.

Thanks so much.

```
private static string GetDirectory(string folderPath, string number)
{
    foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath))
    {
        if (directory.Contains(number))
        {
            return directory;
        }

        GetDirectory(directory, number);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: You could achieve the same in one line: `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folderPath, "*" + number + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier and better to do

```
return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(
        folderPath,
        "*",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(number))
```

or as @TimSchmelter suggests,

```
return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(
        folderPath,
        string.Format("*{0}*", number),
        SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need a `return`:

```
return GetDirectory(directory, number);
```

This will however iterate over one entry in the `foreach`, so this would be better:

```
private static string GetDirectory(string folderPath, string number)
{
    foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath))
    {
        if (directory.Contains(number))
        {
            return directory;
        }

        string result = GetDirectory(directory, number);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi Patrick,

You means:

    private static string GetDirectory(string folderPath, string number)
        {
                    foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath))
                    {
                        if (directory.Contains(number))
                        {
                            return GetDirectory(directory, number);
                        }
                        GetDirectory(directory, number);
                    }
         return null;
        }

I've tried, but it's not work. Please help me!

Comment: @cq0x10glr: I posted the full code. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
private static string GetDirectory(string folderPath, string number)
{
    foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath))
    {
        if (directory.Contains(number))
            return directory;

        var innerDir = GetDirectory(directory, number);
        if (innerDir != null)
            return innerDir;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the same thing, and I think it's more readable:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(number));
```

Comment: Even more concise and efficient: `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folderPath, "*" + number + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault()`